# Undefined control sequence. <argument> ...sub\@captype }}}{\caption@subreffmt

Tags: subcaption, subfig

I'm trying to understand a particular error encountered from using a `subfloat` within a figure. A MWE to reproduce the error:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][A]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:1a}}
\subfloat[\label{fig:1b}][B]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption[abc]{abcdefg}\label{fig:stuff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces the message:

```
./mwe.tex:11: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...sub\@captype }}}{\caption@subreffmt 
                                                  {\@nameuse {p@sub\@captype...
l.11 ...textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:1a}}
                                                  
?
```

If I move the label for the subfloat A within the first `[]` (as done for subfloat B), the example compiles. Removing `subcaption` from the MWE also removes the error without further changes to the MWE, so it's unclear to me if this might be a bug in subcaption, or a convention that I'm not understanding in how the subfloat labels are supposed to be placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't load the package `subfig` together with `subcaption`. Actually, since `subcaption` loads `caption`, the line

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

is sufficient.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][A]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:1a}}
\subfloat[\label{fig:1b}][B]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption[abc]{abcdefg}\label{fig:stuff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```